# Urls getting appended in test cafe

Tags: testcafe

When I trying to click an hyperlink on my app in test cafe it suppose to route to url(https://xxxxxx/test/docs) but the testcafe is appending the hyperlink url with existing page url and trying to load(https://xxxxxx/3PtlNi4ew*xxxdO7Kkw/https://xxxxxx/test/docs). As a result page is failing to load. This issue only happening on test cafe. Please suggest a solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

TestCafe (before version 3.0) uses the URL-rewriting proxy mechanism, which replaces a URL of your target websites. You can find details in the following help topic: https://testcafe.io/documentation/402631/guides/overview/why-testcafe#page-proxying. So, this URL-replacement is expected. It should not lead to failure.

Starting from version 3.0, TestCafe uses the [Native Automation](https://testcafe.io/documentation/404237/guides/intermediate-guides/native-automation-mode) mechanism. Native Automation does not rewrite any URLs. Please note that Native Automation works only in Chromium-based browsers.

Please try to update the TestCafe version to the latest one to use it in Native Automation mode.
If this does not help, please create a separate issue in the official TestCafe GitHub repository using the following link: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=TYPE%3A+bug&projects=&template=bug_report.yaml

Comment: Is there a way to use Native Automation mechanism in TestCafe Studio

Comment: Hello. This is a Testcafe team. At the moment, TestCafe Studio cannot use the native automation mode. We have plans to add it in the next release. Please follow our updates.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue on test cafe version 3.x using these 2 methods.

1. Disable native automation:

   - Use this flag when running tests via CLI

   testcafe chrome tests --disable-native-automation

   - Using configuration

   {
   "disableNativeAutomation": "true"
   }
2. Using a workaround. I used the javascript substring function to fetch the appended URL and used test cafe navigateTo() function to go to the desired target URL.

   const currentUrl = await t.eval(() => window.location.href);

   const targetURL = currentUrl.substring(currentUrl.indexOf('{Your url delimiter}')+ 1, currentUrl.length);

   await t
   .navigateTo(targetURL);